# How to close the Recycle Bin using VB.Net or C#.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

i would like to call a function that Closes the recycle bin window. This is the code that opens the recycle bin, however i can't find the code that closes it :

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/n, ::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417721/adam) has specified you need to use [findwindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [sendmessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx) API to find and then close the window.

Here's a sample code

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Public Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
    Public Const SC_CLOSE As Integer = &HF060



    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim hwnd As IntPtr

        hwnd = FindWindow("CabinetWClass", "Recycle Bin")


        if hwnd = Nothing then
             MessageBox.Show("Recycle Bin not found.")
        else
             SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0)
        end if

    End Sub
End Class
```

Converting the code to c# is pretty easy, still let me know if you face any problem while converting the code.

Source : [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/closewindow.aspx)

**Edit 1 :** You can use Spy++ to find the classname and windowname provided with .net tools.

Answer (score 1):

If it has been opened by someone else you might need to use the win32 api - eg. findwindow then sendmessage to send the close message.

Answer (score 0):

`Process.Start` returns you the `Process` started. Try this:

```
Process p=Process.Start("explorer.exe", 
              "/n, ::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}");
p.CloseMainWindow();
//OR
p.Close();
```

Comment: I just tried that. In my setting, only p.Kill() seems to work.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this doesn't work when the recycle bin is opened from outside my program. so if the user double clicked on it, then i can't reach the process to close it.

Comment: there must some Shell function that does this but i cant seem to find it